# How to get the line of specific text in richTextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a richTextbox which some texts inside. Currently, the "orange" is located in the line 3....so how can i get the line of "orange". My code doesn't work =(

[image]

My C# code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string orange = "orange";
        int a = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(orange);
        var b = richTextBox1.Lines.ElementAt(a);

        textBox1.Text = b.ToString();

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string orange = "orange";

    textBox1.Text = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(
      richTextBox1.Find(orange)
    );
}
```

Refer to the documentation of [RichTextBox.GetLineFromCharIndex(int)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.getlinefromcharindex.aspx) and [RichTextBox.Find(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hfcsf75k.aspx)

Basically `Find(string)` returns the index of the beginning of the string in the text (or `-1` if the string wasn't found), this index is passed to `GetLineFromCharIndex(int)` which in turn retrieves the line number of the specified index.
You may have to handle the special case where your string was not found and `-1` was returned from `Find(string)`.

Comment: +1. Why roll your own function when `GetLineFromCharIndex` exists? :)

Answer (score 0):

You might have to do something to handle multiple lines with the given text, but it should work.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string orange = "orange";

    foreach (string line in richTexBox1.Lines)
        if (line.Contains(orange))
            textBox1.Text = line.ToString();
}
```

Comment: You dont need to split Rich Text box has Lines property which returns all the lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string orange = "orange";
    stringp[] lines = richTextBox1.Lines;
    foreach(string line in lines)
    {
    int a = line.IndexOf(orange);
    if(a >0)
    {
      var b = line.ElementAt(a);

      textBox1.Text = b.ToString();
    }

}
```

Hope that helps