# Find and show multiple Line from specific text in richtextbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-behind

Based from this thread [How to get the line of specific text in richtextbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527105/how-to-get-the-line-of-specific-text-in-richtextbox) I want to ask another question about line of specific text in richtextbox.

From that thread, he wanted to show which line 'orange' text on? 
But, i want to know if he had another 'orange' like

[image: Exmaple image]

From that table, i want to show the line number of 'Orange' text
i expected the output will be "Line 1,2,3,4"

Thank you very much.

Comment: It is a good idea to [edit] your code into a question. You have to use overload of [IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof) which allows to continue searching. Find first occurance, get the line number, find the next one, get the line, etc. .. updated: accepted answer is using [Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.find) method, same with it.

Comment: I used example code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527105/how-to-get-the-line-of-specific-text-in-richtextbox , it worked but only show the first line of highlighted text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a loop and keep track of the index you found the string last in. Something like this should work:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string orange = "orange";
    var index = 0;
    do
    {
        index = richTextBox1.Find(orange, index, RichTextBoxFinds.None);

        if (index >= 0)
        {
            textBox1.Text += richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(index).ToString() + " ";
            index++;
        }
    } while (index >= 0);
}
```

This will find multiple instances of the string "orange" in different lines.

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much bro, it works for me, but somehow, the line starting from 0 rather than 1, i edited 
textBox1.Text += richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(index + 1).ToString() + " ";
but it did'nt do anything.
Thanks anyway

Comment: @RKDev Yes, the index of the rich text box is zero based, so the first line is `0`, the second `1`, and so on. To "convert" it to a one based index, you'd have to add 1 to the result of the `GetLineFromCharIndex` method.

Comment: sir, it worked for 9-10 works, more than that, it has bugs that shows the wrong line numbers where the 11 words belong. 
the output was "Line 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 15"
it should "Line 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 and 10 11" 
and "Line... " after 11, it keeps show wrong Line Number, do you have any solutions? 

I've tried GetFirstLineCharIndexFromLine / GetFirstLineCharIndexOfCurrentTIme, but does'nt work.

Thank you

Comment: @RKDev I can't test it right now, but I think you need to adjust the index modifier. For values > 9 it needs to be `index + 2`, for values > 99 `index + 3` and so on.

Comment: Okay, i'll try doing some hardcode for the -n values. 
I've tried with 100.000 lines text file, from 50k++ lines, between the correct line and the output line is getting wider and wider. Thanks sir :)

Comment: Edit:
I know the problem is, richTextBox in VS max line length is only 3510 based on https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bc4fe581-d7d1-45c4-8d9d-4fe5ad0ffd7f/richtextbox-max-line-lenght?forum=winforms ,
probably my string length at Line 10 is more than 3510, so it automatically wrapped the text and make 4 another lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a small Regex like this :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 1;
    string result = "Line ";

    foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(richTextBox1.Text, "[A-Za-z0-9 ]+"))
    {
        if (match.Value.Contains("Orange"))
            result = $"{result} {i},";
        i++;
    }

    textBox1.Text = result;
}
```

Here is some documentation if you're curious :

- [Regular-expression-language-quick-reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)
- [C# Regex.Match Examples](https://www.dotnetperls.com/regex)

Comment: OP wants to get line numbers, not matches. I don't see how proposed regex solution can help.